# Laravel - how to upload file to another application on localhost?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a file upload where admin would upload file from admin application to another application for regular users (they are on different domains).

I got it working with `FTP filesystem` but I would like to test it on localhost, before I fully deploy it.

I made a config entry in `filesystem.php`:

```
        'ftp' => [
            'driver'   => 'ftp',
            'host'     => env('FTP_HOST'),
            'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
            'root'     => '',
            'port'     => 21,
            'timeout'  => 30,
            'ssl'      => true,
        ]
```

And on my test function in `admin_app` I do this:

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->put('/public_app/storage/test3.png', $file);
```

I have to separate laravel applications: `admin_app` and `public_app`. How could I test the same thing on localhost? Another config entry point or do I need to download FTP for localhost?

Comment: i am pretty sure you need a ftp server in your localhost

Comment: @GiacomoM but is there any other file system method to test it out?

Comment: You mean on another disk not application right?

Comment: @MahanGM another application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using something like remote server that contain your assets?
For example use S3 and upload all your files there and access it from your second app or any other app.
Check this [Article](https://medium.com/@sehmbimanvir/laravel-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-a17d013f53ce)